# When to inject dependency or use as is in Aurelia?

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, aurelia

In Aurelia.js, I see difference examples of how people are injecting dependencies, but haven't found a clear answer on when to explicitly include in inject annotation or use it as is.

For example:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {X} from 'X';
@inject(X)
export class Y {
    constructor(X) {
         this.x = X;
    }
}
```

or

```
import {X} from 'X';
export class Y {
    constructor() {
        this.ABC = someMethod(X); // using X without inject
    }
}
```

Why would someone choose one over the other?

Comment: if my answer was helpful, please upvote and accept :)

Answer (score 4):

Dependency injection is actually a [design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) that Aurelia fully embraces. Though you are not forced to adopt this pattern, it is a best practice as most Aurelia source code you run into will follow this pattern. Core team member [Jeremy Danyow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/725866) has written a brilliant article on this subject in two parts, which I will link below.

Inversion of Control with Aurelia by Jeremy Danyow: [Part 1](https://www.danyow.net/inversion-of-control-with-aurelia-part-1/), [Part 2](https://www.danyow.net/inversion-of-control-with-aurelia-part-2/)

Comment: if this answer was helpful, user2874945, please upvote and accept and I'll be so happy

Answer (score 2):

When you `import X from 'X';` if `X` is a class, an not an instance of a class, you should use Dependency Injection to allow Aurelia to provide you with an instance of the class.

Sometimes though, a module exports function(s) export an object instance. In these cases, you shouldn't use DI.